# Android studio UI issue

Tags: android, android-studio

These popups keep coming when I find usages for a method or variable. And it stays on the screen. Only fixed by restarting the studio. Tried updating and I am using the latest version - Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4 Mac version

[image]